# How to complete form fields automatically in Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Regards! I am creating an inventory system in which, at the time of making the sale, I need to write the code or product name, I need to get the price out of it, without the need to write it manually, however,  I have little knowledge of javascript, I have found several resources like autocomplete of jquery, however, I can not do it, I followed the tutorial of RailsCasts about dynamic selectors, nevertheless I need this to be achieved with text fields, I appreciate immensely someone can help me, specifically in the output model, I have the items in the output_item model, and my product model:

**output_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: output, local: true, id: "form") do |f| %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :invoice %> <br>
            <%= f.text_field :invoice, class: "form-control", placeholder: "CE0001" %>
          </div>      

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :customer %> <br>
            <%= f.text_field :customer, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Ej. Jeovanny" %>
          </div>

          <table width="100%" id="output-item">
            <thead>
              <th>Product</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <th>Options</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <%= f.fields_for :output_items, id: "form" do |item| %>
                <%= render "output_item_fields", f: item %>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div class="form-group mb-0">
            <%= link_to_add_association 'Add product', f, :output_items, :"data-association-insertion-node" => "table#output-item",:"data-association-insertion-method" => "append", class: "btn btn-success" %>        
          </div>      

      <div class="form-group>
          <%= link_to "Cancelar", outputs_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>        
          <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>  
      </div>        

<% end %>
```

**output_items_fields.html.erb**

```
<tr class="item">
    <td><%= f.text_field :product_id, class: "form-control field" %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :quantity, class: "form-control field quantity" %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control field price" %></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control field subtotal"></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <%= link_to_remove_association f, { wrapper_class: "item", class: "btn btn-danger" } do %>
            <i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i>
        <% end %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :input_items
    has_many :output_items
    validates :code, :name, presence: true

    def purchase
        input_items.pluck(:quantity).sum
    end

    def sale
        output_items.pluck(:quantity).sum
    end

    def stock
        (input_items.pluck(:quantity).sum - output_items.pluck(:quantity).sum)
    end

    def price
        self.input_items.sum(:price) / self.input_items.count
    end

end
```

**Output.rb**

```
class Output < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :output_items, inverse_of: :output, :dependent => :delete_all
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :output_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true    

    validates :invoice, :provider, presence: true

end
```

**output_item.rb**

```
class OutputItem < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :output
    validates :quantity, :price, numericality: true, presence: true  

end

class Product < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :output_items

end
```

**input.rb**

```
class Input < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :input_items, inverse_of: :input, :dependent => :delete_all
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :input_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true    

    validates :invoice, :provider, presence: true

end
```

**input_item.rb**

```
class InputItem < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :input
  validates :quantity, :price, numericality: true, presence: true

end
```

**input_migrate.rb**

```
class CreateInputs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :inputs do |t|
      t.string :invoice
      t.string :provider

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**input_items_migration.rb**

```
class CreateInputItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :input_items do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.float :quantity
      t.float :price
      t.belongs_to :input, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**product_migrate.rb**

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :name
      t.float :utility

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**output_migrate.rb**

```
class CreateOutputs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :outputs do |t|
      t.string :invoice
      t.string :customer

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**output_item_migrate.rb**

```
class CreateOutputItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :output_items do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.float :quantity
      t.float :price
      t.belongs_to :output, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The code that RailsCast offers, to autocomplete selectors is with:

```
(function() {
    jQuery(function() {
      var states;
      $('#input_price').parent().hide();
      states = $('#input_price').html();
      return $('#input_product_id').change(function() {
        var country, escaped_country, options;
        country = $('#input_product_id :selected').text();
        escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
        options = $(states).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_country + "']").html();
        if (options) {
          $('#input_price').html(options);
          return $('#input_price').parent().show();
        } else {
          $('#input_price').empty();
          return $('#input_price').parent().hide();
        }
      });
    });

  }).call(this);
```

In what way could adapt, or what is the most convenient way to do this, as an added data, I use cocoon for dynamic items, I appreciate immensely, can help me, Regards!

---

**Updates**

**output_items_fields.html.erb**

```
<tr class="item">
    <td><%= f.text_field :product_id, class: "form-control field" %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :quantity, class: "form-control field quantity" %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control field price" %></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control field subtotal"></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <%= link_to_remove_association f, { wrapper_class: "item", class: "btn btn-danger" } do %>
            <i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i>
        <% end %>
    </td>
</tr>

<% content_for :javascript do %> 
  <script type="text/javascript">var product_info = $.parseJSON('<%= @product_info.to_json.html_safe %>');</script>
<% end %>

<% content_for :javascript do %> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var product_info = $.parseJSON('<%= @product_info.to_json.html_safe %>');
      (function() {
          jQuery(function() {
            var product = product_info[$('#output_product_id')]
            return $('#output_product_id').change(function() {
            if (product) {                     
              $('#output_price').val(product.price);
              $('#output_description').val(product.description);
            } else {
              $('#output_price').val("");
              }
            });
          });
        }).call(this); 
    </script>
<% end %>
```

**outputs_controller.rb**

```
class OutputsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_output, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @output = Output.new
    @output.output_items.build
    @product_info = Product.joins(:input_items).select(:price).all.inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.input_items] = {price: b.price}}  
  end
end
```

When I look for the product_info and testing in the browser console, I get it:

```
console.log(product_info)
Object { price: null }
debugger eval code:1:1
undefined

console.log('testing')
testing debugger eval code:1:1
undefined
```

Comment: When you say "I need to write the code or product name, I need to get the price out of it, without the need to write it manually" what exactly do you mean? Where does the price come from? Does it from from the product name? Do you do a query to get the price when the user enters a product name or code?

Comment: Regards blimbe! I just updated the post, and added my Input model, and InputItem, to make the purchase I store the price within InputItem, which in turn belongs to an Input and a product, when stored within purchase, when I am making a sale, I call the product, and this refers to the price that was added from purchase (InputItem)

Comment: Basically, it's like when you go to the supermarket, scan the code, and automatically appears the description, and price of the product, basically what I'm trying to do, that when selecting or adding the code, complete the fields at the same time, with respective description and price

Comment: So, you would be entering the code of the item(meaning do you want to autocomplete here or user enters the code manually) and then you want to auto populate the information such as the price, description of that item ?

Comment: Exactly Kedarnag, when entering the code within the field (product_id), which is located in the partial output_items_fields.html.erb, I must automatically fill in the "price" field, and I have to add a field that in this case is called the name of the product, which would be product_id, set with its respective name

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have a very large number of products, this is how I would tackle this to auto populate based on model number (if I understand your requirements correctly).  You essentially need to get a Javascript representation of all of your product data, then feed that to jQuery to do the populating, similar to how the Railscast was using country name. And lucky for you, you can easily convert a ruby Hash or Array in to something Javascript can see using .to_json.

First, create a hash that has a key of product model to product price, and populate it from your data source:

```
@product_info = Product.select(:code,:price).all.inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.code] = {price: b.price}}
```

And put that in your controller action.

Next, get that instance variable in to a Javascript variable on your page. This part depends on if you are set up to use content_for :javascript - see [Including inline javascript using content_for in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464595/including-inline-javascript-using-content-for-in-rails) .

```
<% content_for :javascript do %> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var product_info = $.parseJSON(<%= @product_info.to_json.html_safe %>);
  </script>
<% end %>
```

The finally, add this take on the Railscast Code to the content_for block and make it look like the following (replacing the old content_for :javascript block). This part is up to you - if you want a text box that is just populated, or if you want what they had, where you hide and show the field if you can find the values in the hash. I just made it populate it if it could find it, or make it a blank string if it couldn't

```
<% content_for :javascript do %> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var product_info = $.parseJSON(<%= @product_info.to_json.html_safe) %>;
      (function() {
          jQuery(function() {
            return $('#input_product_id').change(function() {
            if (var product = product_info[$('#input_product_id')]) {
              $('#input_price').val(product.price);
            } else {
              $('#input_price').val("");
              }
            });
          });
        }).call(this); 
    </script>
<% end %>
```

#### Issues / Alternatives

Now this would work decently as a first iteration, but there are some issues with it that may apply to you, depending on how you are set up.

The more products you have, the more data you have to spit out as a JSON string. If that string becomes 2, 4, 10 megabytes, it will really slow your users down as they have to load that data just to view your page. You can mitigate that by going a different route and firing off an AJAX call to get the product data as the user types in the model number, and populate the fields as we're doing here. It's not that much more work to go that route as long as you're OK with having an endpoint that gets hit every time the user types something in a text field, and the corresponding database call it needs to make to do the searching.

The other issue is that every time the page loads, you will be re-fetching all of your product data. You would need to start thinking about caching that data either in the view, or in the controller, so that you always load the product model->price/description map from cache instead of fetching it from the database.

Finally, if some other user is entering product information which you want available to power your auto populate code, it would require a page reload. If you don't have that many products being added/changed, this isn't as big of a concern, but if it changes  multiple times per minute/hour, you may want to think about going with the aforementioned solution which fires an AJAX call every time the user types something in, so you can be guaranteed of the latest Product information being returned, rather that some potentially stale representation of all of your product information.

Comment: Greetings, I have implemented the idea, I have applied the code, I have corrected some small syntax errors, but I still do not complete the field, and the console is clean

Comment: Can you confirm in browser dev tools console that you can see the product_info variable ? open browser console and do : console.log(product_info). Can you also confirm that the jQuery onChange handler is firing by adding a console.log('testing') right after  $('#input_product_id').change(function(), reloading the app, changing the text value, and looking at your browser dev tools console? Lastly please suggest edits for syntax errors so I can fix them :)

Comment: bkimble, I just updated the post, with the changes I made

Comment: Awesome. Can you let me know if your onChange handler is firing, and if you can see the JSON object in JS console? Also two things I noticed: 1: you don't see to have an 'output_description' id on any of your fields. I'm not sure which is supposed to represent description, but that should match the ID of that field. and 2: you have the content_for :javascript block in there twice. you only need the bottom one. I was building up the code in the example so I could explain what each step was

Comment: bkimnle, I update the post again with the tests in the browser console

Comment: In this case I do not have a field called description, but "name", so if I can get the price out, I'll append the name field

Comment: On the other hand, if you notice, in the price field, I do not have a select, but an input text, which I would prefer that way, and that I would extract the price, the same would happen with the name field

Comment: So if input_items is an association, you're not properly constructing the map that is required to make this work.  @product_info *must* be a hash where the key is the model number or code or product_id (what ever field you want to do the auto populating from), and the value is a hash of the fields you want to auto populate. If code is that field, this needs to be \@product_info = Product.select(:price,:code).all.inject({}) {|a, b| a[b.code] = {price: b.price}} . If product_id is that field, I'm not sure my solution would work based on my understanding of the problem

Comment: bkimble, in this case price belong to Input Item, code and name belong to product