# How to write JavaScript for Ruby On Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

Let's say I have a website which has the following pages: `Home` `About` `Friends`.

What I want to do is create a simple JavaScript file (called `test.js`), so when a user has pressed a button I can do something simple such as :

```
function myFunction(name) {
  console.log("Name = " + name);
}
```

Now here comes the part where I have my questions. I noticed that ruby uses `project_name/app/views/layout/application.html.erb` and provides the same `<head>` for all three pages (`Home`, `About` and `Friends`).

However, that's not what I want to do here! I only want the `test.js` to work for `Friends` page!

Do I reference that in my `project_name/app/views/home/friends.html.erb` as shown below:

```
<!-- At the bottom of friends.html.erb -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="directory-to-javascript-file"></script>
```

Also I have noticed that there is a JavaScript folder under this directory `project_name/app/javascript` which contains two folders; `channels` and `packs`.

Is this where I want to add my `test.js`, and if so in which folder?

---

So to summaries:

- In which folder do I have to save my `test.js` file?
- Where to reference `test.js` so that it is only visible by `Friends` Page?

Comment: "I noticed that ruby uses project_name/app/views/layout/application.html.erb" this is all Rails and has very little to do with the language.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices for to put the js, the assets pipeline or webpack.
The assets pipeline is maybe a bit simpler to understand,
in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` you can simply put your test function after all the require statements (or extract it to a standalone file and require it). Make sure your application.html.erb has a `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>`

You do not need to put a script tag in friends.html.erb, remove it and let the layout and asset pipeline / webpacker take care of it for you

Second option is to use webpacker. There are quite a few resources written about how to use it with Rails, it's probably better to get familiar with it eventually, I just thought for beginners maybe the old assets pipeline is a bitter easier; the webpack process is very similar though so once you understand one you will easily be able to transfer to the other.

> Where to reference test.js so that it is only visible by Friends Page?

You can create a new layout for the friends controller.

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  layout "friends"
end
```

So in your layouts dir create a friends.html.erb. In friends.html.erb use`<%= javascript_include_tag 'friends' %>`. Next create a manifest (or pack) file for friends:
`app/assets/javascripts/friends.js` and require whatever you need there. This will mean friends controller will get its own layout with its own separate javascript.

Comment: The drawbacks here is that you get an extra http request and the issues involved with a having a persistent browser session - say with turbolinks or Server-Side Concerns which causes the JS to "leak" into contexts you didn't intend. You also don't really need to use layouts - you can use the the captures helper or even script tags in the view instead which causes less code duplication.

Comment: Also when dealing with webpacker you also need to take additonal steps to make that function definition a global so that you can use it in inline JS.

Comment: I agree with @max that this has drawbacks in case you want everything to part of "the same system" e.g using a thing like turbolinks. So its a question of how different these 2 parts are, if they're almost identical go with a yield/capture maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464595/including-inline-javascript-using-content-for-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

you mentioned that you have directory `pack` in `app/javascript`, seems you are using web packer for js and css.

so here is the solution for you.

create a `test.js` inside the `pack` directory.

And write following in to the `project_name/app/views/home/friends.html.erb` that you mentioned in your question.

```rb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'test' %>
```

and write all your js code in `test.js` file. and that will be loaded into only mentioned page.

If you want to same thing with other areas like `home` and `about`. create js files for that and include the `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'js file name' %>` into the appropriate html.erb file.

This will help you have same layout for view of every module, but still have it's own uniq js that required only for specific view.

*You might need to restart the rails server.*

Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you really want to forget the concept of "I just want to load this JS file on this page" - I would consider it an anti-pattern that will hold you back.

Rails uses both [an assets pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) / [webpacker](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html) to streamline your JS delivery, turbolinks to "ajaxify" regular page loads in older versions and Rails UJS does a lot of ajax trickery. Which means that you very likely will be dealing with ajax and persistent browser sessions which make the idea into a real problem as your JS leaks into contexts you didn't intially imagine or just plain won't work unless you're reloading the whole page.

Instead think in terms of [event based programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and behaviors that you can augment UI elements with. Think "I want this kind of button to do X" instead of "I want this specific thing on this page to do X". Use event handlers and css-classes to reach that goal:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => { 
  if (!event.target.matches('.magic-button')) return;
  console.log('You clicked a magical button!');
});
```

This makes your JS decoupled from the page itself and reusable and actually makes your intial problem moot. If you don't want to behavior on other pages then don't add the `magic-button` class.

If you REALLY want to do "per page" javascript one approach that I have used it to attach the `controller_name` and `action_name` to the body element:

```
<body data-controller="<%= controller_name" %>" data-action="<%= action_name %>">
```

That lets you know where you are in your application simply by reading the data attributes:

```
// given controller = foos and action = bar the events are:
// * MyApp:loaded
// * MyApp:foos#bar
// * MyApp:foos
// * MyApp:#bar
const firePageEvents = (event) => {
  // read the data attributes off the body element
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  const details = {
    action: body.dataset.action,
    controller: body.dataset.controller
  };
  const eventNames = [
      "MyApp:loaded", 
      `MyApp:${controller}#${action}`, 
      `MyApp:${controller}`, 
      `MyApp:#${action}`
  ];
  // fire the events
  eventNames.forEach((name) => {
     let event = new CustomEvent(name, { detail: details });
     document.dispatch(event);
  });
}

// fires the events either when turbolinks replaces the page
// or when the DOM is ready
if (window.Turbolinks && Turbolinks.supported) {
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", (event) => { 
    firePageEvents(event);
  });
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => { 
    firePageEvents(event);
  });
}
```

```
// this will be trigged when any page is loaded
document.addEventListener("MyApp:loaded", (event) => {
  switch(event.details.action) {
    case 'about':
      console.log('about page loaded');
      break;
    case 'friends':
      console.log('friends page loaded');
      break;
  }
});

// this will be trigged when the an action named "about" is rendered:
document.addEventListener("MyApp:#about", (event) => {
  console.log('About page loaded', event.details);
});

// this will be triggered on the users load page
document.addEventListener("MyApp:users#index", (event) => {
  console.log('User#index page loaded', event.details);
});
```

We then [fire custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) that you can attach event listeners to make JS fire for specific controllers / actions.

This code belongs in your assets pipeline / packs where its effectivly concatenated and delivered.

Comment: I did do a jQuery based gem ([pagescript](https://rubygems.org/gems/pagescript/versions/0.3.0)) years ago that I havent actively maintaineded.